# How do I obtain the category of a video as displayed on the page with youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to get the category that is shown on the video's page using youtube api. Somehow, however, the video categories returned by the api do not necessarily match what the page says.

```
youtube.videos().list(
                    part="topicDetails",
                    id='JdLCEwEFCMU'
                    ).execute()
```

returns Entertainment and Preforming Arts:

```
topicCategories': [u'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performing_arts',
 u'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entertainment']
```

However, the video is marked as comedy on the page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdLCEwEFCMU

I can definitely see how the categories returned by the api apply, but it is not what I want. My guess is that these are determined by google, which the on page one is defined by the user. Short of scraping the page with Beautiful Soup or something, how do I get this category?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? If you define `part=snippet` then it will return the video's `categoryId`. You'd then have to query `VideoCategories` to get the text representation. Following those steps, I get a `categoryId` of 23 for the video you reference, which does translate to 'Comedy.'

Comment: Yep, thanks. That works. I tried using snippet for search() instead of video and it would never return category id. I thought it was outdated.